For a separable covariance in a Gaussian process, is an inverse Wishart prior conjugate?
Suppose we have a GP for the vector $\mathbf{y}\sim\text{GP}(\boldsymbol{0},\Sigma_y)$, where $\Sigma_y=\Sigma_r\otimes\Sigma_f$ is a separable covariance matrix. Assume $\Sigma_f$ is fixed and an Inverse Wishart prior $\Sigma_r\sim\text{IW}(\nu_0,\Psi_0)$. Is the inverse Wishart conjugate here? So far, I have the following steps:
$$p(\Sigma_r|\mathbf{y})\propto p(\mathbf{y}|\Sigma_r)p(\Sigma_r)\propto|\Sigma_r|^{-(\nu_0+d+n+1)/2}\exp\left\{-\frac12\mathbf{y}^T(\Sigma_r^{-1}\otimes\Sigma_f^{-1}\mathbf{y}) - \frac12 \text{tr}(\Psi_0\Sigma_r^{-1})\right\},$$
where $\Sigma_f$ is a $d\times d$ matrix. To get this far, I used the following Kronecker properties: (i) $|A\otimes B|=|A|^m|B|^n$, where $A$ is $n\times n$ and $B$ is $m\times m$, and (ii) $(A\otimes B)^{-1}=A^{-1}\otimes B^{-1}$. It seems like it should be conjugate, but I'm not sure how to simplify the exponential term in such a way.

You were almost there :). You reached the correct form of the posterior but needed to recognise that the exponential term and the determinant term together indicated that the posterior was indeed in the form of an inverse Wishart distribution:
$$ p(\Sigma_r | \mathbf{y}) \propto |\Sigma_r|^{-(\nu_0 + d + n + 1)/2} \exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{2} \text{tr}\left( \left( \Psi_0 + Y^T \Sigma_f^{-1} Y \right) \Sigma_r^{-1} \right) \right\}. $$
You could have identified that this matched the kernel of an inverse Wishart distribution:
$$ \Sigma_r | \mathbf{y} \sim \text{IW}\left(\nu_0 + d, \Psi_0 + Y^T \Sigma_f^{-1} Y\right), $$
thereby confirming that the inverse Wishart prior is conjugate in this case.

I will try to write it out fully. We have:

A GP with vector $\mathbf{y} \sim \text{GP}(\mathbf{0}, \Sigma_y)$,
The separable covariance matrix $\Sigma_y = \Sigma_r \otimes \Sigma_f$,
A fixed $\Sigma_f$,
An inverse Wishart prior on $\Sigma_r$, $\Sigma_r \sim \text{IW}(\nu_0, \Psi_0)$.

Here, $\Sigma_f$ is a $d \times d$ matrix, and $\Sigma_r$ is an $n \times n$ matrix.
The goal is to determine if the posterior distribution $p(\Sigma_r | \mathbf{y})$ is also an inverse Wishart distribution, which would imply conjugacy.
Prior Distribution
The prior distribution for $\Sigma_r$ is:
$$ p(\Sigma_r) \propto |\Sigma_r|^{-(\nu_0 + n + 1)/2} \exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{2} \text{tr}(\Psi_0 \Sigma_r^{-1}) \right\}, $$
where $n$ is the dimension of $\Sigma_r$.
Likelihood
Given $\mathbf{y} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}, \Sigma_r \otimes \Sigma_f)$, the likelihood function is:
$$ p(\mathbf{y} | \Sigma_r) \propto |\Sigma_r \otimes \Sigma_f|^{-1/2} \exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{2} \mathbf{y}^T (\Sigma_r^{-1} \otimes \Sigma_f^{-1}) \mathbf{y} \right\}. $$
Using the properties of the Kronecker product:
$$
\begin{align}
|\Sigma_r \otimes \Sigma_f| &= |\Sigma_r|^d |\Sigma_f|^n, \\
(\Sigma_r \otimes \Sigma_f)^{-1} &= \Sigma_r^{-1} \otimes \Sigma_f^{-1}
\end{align}
$$
we can rewrite the likelihood as:
$$ p(\mathbf{y} | \Sigma_r) \propto |\Sigma_r|^{-d/2} \exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{2} \mathbf{y}^T (\Sigma_r^{-1} \otimes \Sigma_f^{-1}) \mathbf{y} \right\}, $$
where $d$ is the dimension of $\Sigma_f$.
Posterior Distribution
Combining the prior and the likelihood, the posterior distribution is:
$$ p(\Sigma_r | \mathbf{y}) \propto p(\mathbf{y} | \Sigma_r) p(\Sigma_r) \propto |\Sigma_r|^{-(\nu_0 + n + d + 1)/2} \exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{2} \left( \text{tr}(\Psi_0 \Sigma_r^{-1}) + \mathbf{y}^T (\Sigma_r^{-1} \otimes \Sigma_f^{-1}) \mathbf{y} \right) \right\}. $$
Simplification of the Exponential Term
To simplify the term in the exponent, consider the form:
$$ \mathbf{y}^T (\Sigma_r^{-1} \otimes \Sigma_f^{-1}) \mathbf{y}. $$
Since $\mathbf{y}$ can be reshaped into a matrix $Y$ where $Y$ is an $n \times d$ matrix, this term can be represented as:
$$ \text{vec}(Y)^T (\Sigma_r^{-1} \otimes \Sigma_f^{-1}) \text{vec}(Y) = \text{tr}(Y^T \Sigma_f^{-1} Y \Sigma_r^{-1}). $$
Thus, the posterior becomes:
$$ p(\Sigma_r | \mathbf{y}) \propto |\Sigma_r|^{-(\nu_0 + n + d + 1)/2} \exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{2} \left( \text{tr}(\Psi_0 \Sigma_r^{-1}) + \text{tr}(Y^T \Sigma_f^{-1} Y \Sigma_r^{-1}) \right) \right\}. $$
Summing Up:
The form of the posterior distribution is:
$$ p(\Sigma_r | \mathbf{y}) \propto |\Sigma_r|^{-(\nu_0 + n + d + 1)/2} \exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{2} \text{tr}\left( \left( \Psi_0 + Y^T \Sigma_f^{-1} Y \right) \Sigma_r^{-1} \right) \right\}. $$
This is recognizable as the kernel of an inverse Wishart distribution:
$$ \Sigma_r | \mathbf{y} \sim \text{IW}\left(\nu_0 + d, \Psi_0 + Y^T \Sigma_f^{-1} Y\right). $$
Therefore, the inverse Wishart prior is conjugate to the Gaussian process with a separable covariance structure $\Sigma_y = \Sigma_r \otimes \Sigma_f$ when $\Sigma_f$ is fixed.

Thank you for the response, Robert! I was missing that reshaping step. That is clever. I'll be aware of that step for future solutions.

You’re welcome. I’m glad that it helps. Often these kinds of things are not obvious (unless you’re some kind of math genius, which I’m definitely not ), and unless you’ve seen it done before (as I had) then you get stumped.

I appreciate it. The original bounty expired, so I set a new one which I can award tomorrow. Thank you again, Robert :)

Thank you , Ron  :)

Thank you for the bounty, Ron

Thank you for your help :)
